# Quick switching to maximized application on Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard, spaces

I used to use spaces for quick switching between applications (I had a space with a browser, another with a terminal and yet another with an editor). For spaces I could have a keyboard shortcut. This way, I had a quick way to switch using a keyboard shortcut.

Lion introduced maximized applications. I find this a great feature, however, after maximization the application it is on its own space for which I do not know how to define a keyboard shortcut.

Could you give me a hint how to quickly, using a keyboard shortcut, access a maximized application on Lion?

Thank you!

Comment: I assume you don't have a multitouch trackpad, right? Isn't the application switcher Cmd+Tab fast enough? Otherwise you can create a shortcut to go left/right in Mission Control like in Snow Leopard.

Comment: Cmd+Tab needs hitting the Tab more times. There applications like the browser, terminal and editor. I'd like to get to these in one step. I do not have a multitouch trackpad.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788565/keyboard-shortcut-to-focus-on-an-app-in-mac-os

Answer (score 1):

Use Ctrl + the arrow keys:

**Ctrl + Right**: switch to next space / maximized app to the right.

**Ctrl + Left**: switch to next space / maximized app to the left

**Ctrl + Up**: Exposé / Mission control showing everything

**Ctrl + Down**: Exposé for just the windows of the current app

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences:  Keyboard: Keyboard Shortcuts:

Select "Mission Control" on the left.

Scroll down to the "Mission Control" section on the right.

Turn on the check boxes next to the "Switch to Desktop x" entries.